# IntelliJ not showing the root directory of the project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project that has the following structure:

- 'app' directory containing java code (maven)
- 'docker' containing Dockerfile and shell scripts to put into the docker image
- build scripts in the root directory, that orchestrate both builds

When I import my project to the IntelliJ, I see the whole content, however, the project is not recognized as the java project.

When I click on the pom.xml and do 'Add as a maven project', the 'app' directory is added as the only module and I don't see 'docker' or anything in the root directory :
[image]

I can add manually 'docker' as a module, but when I try to do the same with the root directory, nothign happens. The only was to edit files in the root directory is to do that from the commmand line.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the directory as a module if it is already included into one of the modules. If you want to have the root directory to be the directory above the `app` - open this directory from File | Open action first (delete the `.idea` configuration if exists before this). Then add maven module from pom.xml file context menu in Project tool window or maven tool window.

If the `docker` directory has separate source files and you want to extract it into a separate Java module use File | New | Module from Existing Sources... action to create a module out of it.

Comment: I was adding maven module via clicking on pom.xml -> add as maven project